# Preserve the font spacing of a line of text split into individual HTML elements

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to recreate a common technique where words are split into individual HTML elements so that they can be targeted individually with animations.

The issue I am having is that when they get split into individual elements, I lose the spacing between words. By rendering each word with a `&nbsp;` after it, or adding padding to each element, I can add spacing, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this where I don't have to manually add a spacer/flex them across a container and can preserve the original spacing?

I know there are plugins like gsap SplitText for this, but I am hoping for non-plugin solution.

[Codepen Here.](https://codepen.io/rnrh/pen/OJBvvKR)

```
const App = () => {
  const line = 'this is a line of text.';
  const renderLine = line.split(' ').map((word, i) => {
    return (
      <span key={i}>{word}&nbsp;</span>
    )
  })

  return (
    <h1>{renderLine}</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why are the 'normal' space characters removed?

Comment: @AHaworth That is what i'm trying to figure out. I'm not sure of the way to render it where they aren't removed with the split() approach I'm using.

Comment: Any reason not to put them back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex `/\b/` this will search for word boundaries and will split the line in words and white spaces.

```js
function App() {
  const line = "this is a line of text.";
  const renderLine = line.split(/\b/).map((word, i) => {
    return <span key={i}>{word}</span>;
  });

  return <h1>{renderLine}</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```